# Node command doesn't execute asterisk path

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, npm

I have a folder Test/Automation contains many test cases, e.g. a.js, b.js, c.js, etc.

I am using WebdriverJs Selenium. I use this command to execute all the tests in this folder:

```
node Test/**/*.js
```

But only a.js was executed and then it's done. Anyone knows the reason why? Is there something wrong with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I have found a solution, I wrapped Js in mocha format, then I can them all with this command :

```
mocha Test/Automation/*.js
```

It works as I want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare that js in server.js.
For example:

```
var express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
modulea = require('./modules/a'),
moduleb = require('./modules/b')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple *.js (javascript) files in same directory as well. node wont run multiple files in same command line. eg if you had a.js,b.js,c.js within test and then,

```
node test/*.js
```

will return output of a.js only.

Another proposal,
Assuming you doing some form of automation with different scenarios,

try creating a batch executable (or bash script in case of linux) with something like this,

```
node test/l1/a.js
node test/l1/a1.js
node test/l2/b.js
```

this will give you additional option to control test/js to execute.